# Xcode debugger -- allow breakpoints to work while evaluating something from a breakpoint?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Is this possible?  For example, if I am stopped at a breakpoint, and I enter

```
po [foo description]
```

into the console, the debugger will print the description of foo.  But if it hits another breakpoint while computing said description, it will not break at the second breakpoint.

Can I alter this behavior so that it does break at the second breakpoint?

Comment: Why don't you add the line [foo description] after the first breakpoint, in the code?